# Color Theme editor VS 2015: Cannot Create New Color Theme

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vs-color-theme-editor

I am using VS 2015 Enterprise Edition. I have installed Color Themes Editor via NuGet. In the video description on [VS Color Theme editor Video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/Visual-Studio-2012-Color-Theme-Editor) I can see that the extension supports creation of new themes resp. editing of existing ones, as in the following picture: 
[image: Fig. 1] In my VS there is no left box with "New Theme", but only the preview of the prefabricated ones, as the the second picture:
[image: Fig 2]

What can the problem be or what do I miss?

Answer (score 0):

To create a custom theme, you first need to copy an existing theme:
[image]

After the copy is created, you can edit and rename it:

[image]

This seems to be obvious and intuitive, but I failed to find it in the description.